# Beginner - C# Fractional Calculator simplification of negative fractions

Tags: c#, calculator, simplify

I've been having troubles trying to get my fractional calculator to work. I'm trying to get the simplifying to work, it works correctly simplifiyng positive fractions, but if I were to put a negative fraction it won't simplify it, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I've read over it numerous times (the Gcd and Reduce functions).

Im new to all of this, any help appreciated.

My Reduce and GCD functions:

```
public int gcd()
{
    // assigned x and y to the answer Numerator/Denominator, as well as an  
    // empty integer, this is to make code more simple and easier to read
    int x = answerNumerator;
    int y = answerDenominator;
    int m;

    // check if numerator is greater than the denominator, 
    // make m equal to denominator if so
    if (x > y)
        m = y;
    else
        // if not, make m equal to the numerator
        m = x;

    // assign i to equal to m, make sure if i is greater
    // than or equal to 1, then take away from it
    for (int i = m; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0)
        {
            //return the value of i
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

public void Reduce()
{
    try
    {
        //assign an integer to the gcd value
        int gcdNum = gcd();

        if (gcdNum != 0)
        {
            answerNumerator = answerNumerator / gcdNum;
            answerDenominator = answerDenominator / gcdNum;
        }

        if (answerDenominator < 0)
        {
            answerDenominator = answerDenominator * -1;
            answerNumerator = answerNumerator * -1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        // display the following error message 
        // if the fraction cannot be reduced
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Cannot reduce Fraction: " + exp.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: A general comment: Your functions would be better if they took parameters instead of relying and acting on global variables.

Comment: Can you give an example of a "negative fraction"? Is it simply where either `answerNumerator` or `answerDenominator` are less than zero?

Comment: By negative fraction I mean this. I put 1 1/2 - 4 1/4 in the calculator and I get -2 -6/8 instead of -2 3/4.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: That code isn't showing, but internally you are only storing the numerator and denominator, right? So even though you display `1 1/2`, internally you store it as `numerator = 3; denominator = 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that, when you determine the GCD, you are checking that the value is `>= 1` in your `for` loop, even though it may be negative. In order to avoid this, you should capture the absolute values of the numerator and denominator when determining the GCD.

For example, this should fix it:

```
public int gcd()
{
    // assigned x and y to the absolute values of the answer Numerator/Denominator, 
    // as well as an empty integer, this is to make code more simple and easier to read
    int x = Math.Abs(answerNumerator);
    int y = Math.Abs(answerDenominator);
    int m;

    // check if numerator is greater than the denominator, 
    // make m equal to denominator if so
    if (x > y)
        m = y;
    else
        // if not, make m equal to the numerator
        m = x;

    // assign i to equal to m, make sure if i is greater
    // than or equal to 1, then take away from it
    for (int i = m; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0)
        {
            //return the value of i
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

You need:

```
int x = Math.Abs(answerNumerator);
int y = Math.Abs(answerDenominator);
```

## Running Code

Here is a running Fiddle for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBzr0i

Output:

```
Initial: 2/4
Reduced: 1/2
---
Initial: 2/-4
Reduced: -1/2
---
```

Running Code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Calc.Reduce(2,4);
        Calc.Reduce(2,-4);
    }
}

public static class Calc
{
    public static int gcd(int answerNumerator, int answerDenominator)
    {
        // assigned x and y to the answer Numerator/Denominator, as well as an  
        // empty integer, this is to make code more simple and easier to read
        int x = Math.Abs(answerNumerator);
        int y = Math.Abs(answerDenominator);
        int m;
        // check if numerator is greater than the denominator, 
        // make m equal to denominator if so
        if (x > y)
            m = y;
        else
            // if not, make m equal to the numerator
            m = x;
        // assign i to equal to m, make sure if i is greater
        // than or equal to 1, then take away from it
        for (int i = m; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (x % i == 0 && y % i == 0)
            {
                //return the value of i
                return i;
            }
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public static void Reduce(int answerNumerator, int answerDenominator)
    {
        Console.Write("Initial: ");
        WriteFraction(answerNumerator, answerDenominator);

        try
        {
            //assign an integer to the gcd value
            int gcdNum = gcd(answerNumerator, answerDenominator);
            if (gcdNum != 0)
            {
                answerNumerator = answerNumerator / gcdNum;
                answerDenominator = answerDenominator / gcdNum;
            }

            if (answerDenominator < 0)
            {
                answerDenominator = answerDenominator * -1;
                answerNumerator = answerNumerator * -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            // display the following error message 
            // if the fraction cannot be reduced
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot reduce Fraction: " + exp.Message);
        }

        Console.Write("Reduced: ");
        WriteFraction(answerNumerator, answerDenominator);
        Console.WriteLine("---");
    }

    public static void WriteFraction(int answerNumerator, int answerDenominator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", answerNumerator, answerDenominator));
    }
}
```